# "Movement like an eagle/lightning/etc."

Tags: syntax

Can "like" be used as in "movement like an eagle/lightning/etc"?

I'm wondering because even though I searched, I could get sayings like (he saw his) movement like an eagle (seeing preys). But I wonder "like" can be used with nouns.

Comment: "prey" is uncountable, so not "preys".  ---- If you don't use "like" with a noun, how else would you use it?  Isn't it (nearly) always used with a noun?

Comment: @JamesK I think I've always used it as adverbs: "he soared like a bird"; "he walked slowly like a slug.

Comment: But 'bird' and 'slug' are nouns. not adverbs.

Comment: OP is referring to the use of *like* after a noun, as in *movement like*.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore Exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Movement like an eagle" is a clumsy phrase because an eagle is not a form of movement. You are comparing an action to a bird.

You could certainly say, "He moved like an eagle", or, "His movement was like an eagle's".

"Like" can certainly be used with nouns. You just need two nouns that are in the same "category". Like, "This animal I just discovered is like a frog." "My school is like a prison." "His book is like real life." Etc.

It would be decidedly strange to say, "This animal is like loneliness" or "My school is like the color blue." Maybe such a comparison would make sense in context.

I suppose "Movement like an eagle" could be understood to mean "movement like the movement of an eagle". That's probably how I'd take it if I read it. But it doesn't actually say that, I have to add words to the sentence to make it make sense.